# Add HTTP header into response for index.html

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, http-headers

In JavaEE application.
I have index.html page as "welcome-file" in web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**I want to add Http Header into response for index.html**

One way is use index.jsp instead of index.html and add inside an scriptlet:

```
<% response.addHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");  %>
```

Is there any other way?
Is there an possiblility to add some kind of filter
For example something like:

```
WelcomeFileFilter {
  void filter(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.addHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
  }
}
```

Because I don't want to use index.jsp instead of index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely add a filter,

try - [responseheaderfilter](http://code.google.com/p/responseheaderfilter/)

Comment: Unfortunatelly it seems, that filter do not apply, when welcome-file is index.html. It is applyed only if welcome-file is index.jsp :-(

Comment: Sorry filter works fine. I had wrong mapping "/*". I changed it into "*" and now it works fine.

Comment: responseheaderfilter is old and not maintained anymore (last code evol in Jun. 2009) and has some serious bugs like this one : http://code.google.com/p/responseheaderfilter/issues/detail?id=2 Why do you want to use a lib when the standard JavaEE covers all your needs ?

Comment: Don't use this solution, use this one instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26875465/1583422

Answer (score 1):

You can ask your web server/servlet container to add those headers for you. It will be configured in the server configuration files not in web.xml.

Or you can create a filter that will add headers for you. You'll have to configure the filter in your web.xml.

This [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009631/setting-http-headers-with-jetty/12125253#12125253) show you how to configure jetty to add headers. This other [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3013315/3673) shows you how to code a Filter that add headers.